# Получить реальное место возникновения ошибки

Tags: c#, .net

Если я ловлю ошибку в методе, а затем в блоке `catch` делаю throw этой ошибки на верх, то в стеке ошибок пишется именно, что ошибочной строкой является `throw`.

Можно ли как-то получить реальное место возникновения ошибки?

Пример кода:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var t = 1;
            var t3 = 2;
            var t4 = t - t3;
            throw new Exception("BlaBla bla");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут у меня пишется, что исключение возникло не в `throw new Exception("BlaBla bla");` , а на строчке с `throw`;

Comment: @Igor вы имеете ввиду запускать в релизе, а не дебаг?

Comment: Вместо `throw new Exception...` напишите `double.Parse("one-two-three");`

Answer (score 8):

Делайте

```
throw; // перебросить с оригинальным стектрейсом
```

А не

```
throw ex; // бросить заново и потерять стектрейс
```

---

К сожалению, если исключение было брошено, поймано, и переброшено в одном и том же методе - строчка в стектрейсе поменяется даже в случае если был использован `throw;`. CLR использует SEH, а тот использует стекфремы для отслеживания цепочки вызовов. На один метод - один стекфрейм, так что перебрасывание исключения в рамках одного метода перетирает оригинальный stack trace.

Т.е. любой метод бросания исключения - и `throw;`, и `throw ex;` - изменяют стектрейс. Просто первый сохраняет более глубокие фреймы, а второй - нет.

Вопрос на английском: [enSO: Incorrect stacktrace by rethrow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4217616/1988244)

Comment: Хм... у меня все равно почему-то на блок catch указывается...

Comment: В режиме Debug StackTrace содержит номер строки - в этой строке у Вас `throw something;` или код, который приводит к новому исключению.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Приведите минимальный пример

Comment: @PashaPash готово.

Comment: @iluxa1810 дописал про случай перебрасывания в одном методе

Answer (score 5):

Это можно сделать на современном C#, хотя и не так изящно, как хотелось бы.

Вам нужно поместить логику до `throw` в фильтр исключений, и вернуть из него `false` для случая, когда исключение нужно пробросить. При этом код вообще не будет заходить в `catch`.

Вместо метода

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = 1;
    try
    {
        var t3 = 2;
        var t4 = t - t3;
        throw new Exception("BlaBla bla");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception with message {ex.Message} thrown, t = {t}");
        throw;
    }
}
```

(тут в `StackTrace` только строка с `throw`)
у вас получится вот такое:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = 1;
    try
    {
        var t3 = 2;
        var t4 = t - t3;
        throw new Exception("BlaBla bla");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (Filter(ex))
    {
    }

    bool Filter(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception with message {ex.Message} thrown, t = {t}");
        return false;
    }
}
```

(в `StackTrace` только строка с `throw new Exception("BlaBla bla");`).

Ещё один популярный (в узких кругах) вариант — использование `System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo`. Вот такой код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = 1;
    try
    {
        var t3 = 2;
        var t4 = t - t3;
        throw new Exception("BlaBla bla");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception with message {ex.Message} thrown, t = {t}");
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex).Throw();
    }
}
```

производит `StackTrace` из **двух** частей:

```
   at Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in ...\Program.cs:line 38
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in ...\Program.cs:line 43
```

Строка 38 содержит `throw new Exception("BlaBla bla");`, а строка 43 — `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex).Throw();`.

(Я вынес переменную `t`, чтобы к ней можно было обращаться из блока `catch` ну или из локальной функции.)

Ограничение метода: невозможно использовать `async`-метод в фильтре.

---

При большом желании, фильтр можно и заинлайнить. Синтаксис при этом становится совсем вырвиглазным.

Answer (score 2):

Можно:

```
try
{
  ...
}
catch(ExceptionType ex)
{
  throw; // а не throw ex;
}
```